# How to simulate double-click bug in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, double-click

Recently I noticed a double-click bug in my code, and after some investigation, I decided that there is a bug in the following component:

```
function ActionButton(props) {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <button disabled={disabled} onClick={async () => {
            // We must check that disabled == false
            setDisabled(true);
            await props.onClick();
            setDisabled(false);
        }}>
            Click
        </button>
    );
}
```

This component tries to prevent double-clicks for some non-idempotent action, but it does this badly because there is no check for `disabled` state in the `onClick` handler. Because of this in the case when event-loop contains more than one `MouseClick` event there can be multiple calls of `props.onClick` function.

Now I want to reproduce this bug, but it's not too easy for me, because I don't understand how to create a situation when the event loop contains many `MouseClick` events.

I tried to reproduce the bug with the following code, but for some reasons (which I don't understand) this doesn't work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  }));
}
```

So, I have the following questions:

1. Is it true, that this component doesn't truly prevent double-click or my explanation is wrong and React has some guarantees that natively prevent this bug in my example?
2. How can I reproduce the bug with programmatically created events?
3. How can I manually reproduce the bug? Are there some tooling/extension in the browser, that can help to reproduce this kind of bugs? For example, network throttling is very useful for testing a different kind of data-races in the local environment.

Comment: you can use cancellable promises to achieve this https://medium.com/trabe/prevent-click-events-on-double-click-with-react-with-and-without-hooks-6bf3697abc40

Comment: @AafaqAhmad, thank you for the interesting article, but how cancellable promises can help me to reproduce the bug? If I get it right, the article contains a solution for distinguishing onClick and onDoubleClick events.

Comment: i guess if you are able to resolve with this solution then there is no need to simulate the bug again, anyways to reproduce this you try dispatching the event using a setTimeout inside your loop.